# Shortcut for adding `org-mode` environment

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm using `org-mode` for organizing myself (very useful so far!). However, it is kind of annoying writing

```
  #+begin_comment
  ...
  #+end_comment
```

each time I'd like to insert an environment.

**Question**

Is there a shortcut to insert the `#+begin_` and `#+end_` for a given environment?

In the same way `C-c C-o comment RET` would insert

```
\begin{comment}

\end{comment}
```

in `latex-mode`.

Comment: -1. Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/653478/shortcut-for-inserting-environments-in-org-mode and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145433/shortcut-for-inserting-environments-in-org-mode.

Comment: @echristopherson please don't down vote people for posting duplicates. Not even if they're dupes from the _same_ site (in that case just flag/close) and most certainly not if they're dupes on _other_ sites. Instead take one of the other answers, adapt as necessary and post it here (giving the source, obviously). See [here](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/1396/22222) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137861/203101).

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried to take back my vote but it's been too long.

Comment: @echristopherson no worries, try again, you should be able to retract now that the post has been edited. You may as well make an answer out of the linked ones and get some rep :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using so-called Easy Templates. See [the org-mode manual for the default list](http://orgmode.org/manual/Easy-Templates.html).

If you add the following to your `.emacs` file, you will be able to insert a comment by simply typing `<c` followed by the `TAB` key for a comment or `<e[TAB]` for an example, etc.:

```
(setq org-structure-template-alist
  '(("s" "#+begin_src ?\n\n#+end_src" "<src lang=\"?\">\n\n</src>")
    ("e" "#+begin_comment\n?\n#+end_comment"))
```

Note that this will overwrite the default Easy Templates. To add your Easy Template to the default list without overwriting the whole list (although the default `<e` for the default example environment will be overwritten) add this to your `.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
    '("e" "#+begin_comment ?\n\n#+end_comment"))
```